# php include file name stored in as variable

Tags: php

I have to include a file stored in a database and retrieved  as a variable.
how can I do it? I have tried this line but it doesn't work
 **include_once("News/$post->newspage");** 
the fild newspage contains the names of the files stored in News folder. for example his line works.
  include_once("News/labourday2014.php");

Comment: In addition to the answers below you should probably also check that the file exists before including it.

Answer (score 2):

you can try like

```
include_once("News/".$post->newspage);
```

Answer (score 2):

`include_once("News/{$post->newspage}");` should do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Verify if the file exist then include it

```
if(is_file("News/".$post->newspage)) {
   include_once("News/".$post->newspage);
} else {
    // File dosent't exist
    echo "File dosent't exist";
}
```

Comment: I have checked the existance of the file but I still get the same error.Warning: include_once(/home2/umutarap/public_html/nyagatareweb_dev/News) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: Success in /home2/umutarap/public_html/nyagatareweb_dev/index.php on line 141

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'News/' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home2/umutarap/public_html/nyagatareweb_dev/index.php on line 141

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
$fileName="News/".$post->newspage;
include_once($fileName);
```